# PhpSpec return always null on mocks

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpspec

I'm working with PhpSpec and for some reason when I mock my dependencies and call them the `willReturn` method of PhpSpec give me a `null` value instead of the value passed.

This is the method that I'm trying to describe

```
    /**
     * Register an User
     *
     * @param array $infoUser
     * @return User
     */
    public function register(array $infoUser)
    {

        $user = $this->user->create($infoUser);

        $this->raise(new UserRegistered($user));

        return $user;
    }
```

My Spec

```
class BaseAuthSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType('Core\Auth\BaseAuth');
    }

    function let(AuthManager $guard,UserAuthRepository $user)
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($guard,$user);
    }

    function it_register_an_user(UserAuthRepository $useRepo)
    {
        $user = [
            'username' => 'fabri',
            'email'    => 'test@test.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'repeat_password' => 'password'
        ];

        $userModel = new User($user);

        // this line return null instead the $userModel
        $useRepo->create($user)->shouldBeCalled()->willReturn($userModel);

        $this->raise(new UserRegistered($userModel))->shouldReturn(null);

        $this->register($user)->shouldReturn($userModel);
    }
}
```

I'm stuck with this issue, any suggest will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments are matched by name. The user repository passed to your `let()` method, is not the same as passed to the `it_register_an_user()` method. To fix your issue, simply give it the same name.

There're other issues in your spec.

It's not possible to mock nor stub a method on the class you're speccing. This is not going to work:

```
$this->raise(new UserRegistered($userModel))->shouldReturn(null);
```

I'm not sure what's going on in the `raise()` method, but you should deal with it properly in your example, so either stub or mock any collaborators (or leave them alone if there's no return values relevant to the current example).

Another thing is that you use mocks when what you really need is stubs. I'd rewrite your example to be:

```php
class BaseAuthSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function let(AuthManager $guard, UserAuthRepository $userRepo)
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($guard, $user);
    }

    function it_registers_a_user(UserAuthRepository $userRepo, User $userModel)
    {
        $user = [
            'username' => 'fabri',
            'email'    => 'test@test.com',
            'password' => 'password',
            'repeat_password' => 'password'
        ];

        $userRepo->create($user)->willReturn($userModel);

        $this->register($user)->shouldReturn($userModel);
    }
}
```

The raise method should be covered by seperate examples.